# What is the name of a data structure that acts like a shift register

Tags: arrays, list, data-structures, naming

It has a predetermined finite size, and when you 'push' a new value on, it becomes the new 'head' and all other values are moved down the line. The last value in the list is discarded. I know of several different ways to implement this, that's not the problem.

My question is, is there a standard name for this type of data structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a [queue](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Queue_%28data_structure%29) comes closest.

Comment: That's probably it if nothing comes closer. I thought it might have a specialised name

Answer (score 1):

A [ring buffer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_buffer).

Comment: A ring buffer is one way to implement the queue data structure he was looking for.

Answer (score -2):

I believe the correct name for this structure is Stack. You push new items on top of the stack, and take items from the top. Also known as LIFO (Last In First Out).

Comment: Not really - he said **finite size** and the "bottom" element gets discarded when a new "top" element is added.

Comment: Paul, I think that's just an implementation detail of the particular one you're using. The size and what happens when it fills up aren't generally defined at this high level.